# Simple jquery deferred queue

Tags: javascript, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have a method **foo(param)** that is synchronous.

I would like be free to call **foo(param)** without executing the actual foo() call until a particular event later in time.

It looks like a good candidate for deferred / promise but I must be doing something wrong since the timeout does not have any effect.

Should the log method return promise?

```js
var log = function(message) {
    $('#log').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
};

$(function() {
 
    var q = new $.Deferred();
    
    q.then(log("1"));
    q.then(log("2"));
    q.then(log("3"));
    q.then(log("4"));
    q.then(log("5"));
    q.then(log("6"));
    q.then(log("7"));
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        q.resolve();
    }, 10000);
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your lines that say `q.then(log("..."))` should say `q.then(function() { log("...") })`.

Your `log` function is fine but the way your code currently works is that you are *already calling it* and passing its return value to the `then` function. That's why you need to create a new function which the deferred will call later when it resolves.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `q.then(log("1"));` it's attempting to get the function value of "`log("1")`" to pass to the then function. This is evaluating the function which is the reason why you're seeing them in the console instead of what you intend.

Wrapping them like so, should fix your problem:

```
q.then(function() {
    log("1")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you should write depends entirely on what is meant by "until a particular event later".

The can be interpreted in two ways.

**User Event:** A user event (in a browser) is something like a 'click' or a 'mouseover'. It's occurrence *is not* determined by anything in javascript/jQuery and it may never happen. However, by attaching an event handler, you can ensure that if/when the event does happen, a predetermined course of action is taken.

The log sequence would be established as follows :

```
$(selector).on('eventType', function() {
    log("1");
    log("2");
    log("3");
    log("4");
    log("5");
    log("6");
    log("7");
});
```

**Asycnchronous Response:** An asynchronous response is an event that occurs when an asynchronous process completes. It's occurrence is determined by (a) the aync process being initiated and (b) its eventual completion. Again, completion may never happen but is more guaranteed than with a user event. A well written aync process should guarantee to complete (successfully or unsuccessfully).

The log sequence would be established as follows :

```
asyncProcess().then(function() {
    log("1");
    log("2");
    log("3");
    log("4");
    log("5");
    log("6");
    log("7");
});
```

As you can see, in both cases the log() statements are straightforward sequential lines of code.

It's unnecessary in either case to establish a Promise chain as `log()` is itself synchronous. However, if you want to explore the nature of Deferreds/Promises, then the asynchronous version could be written as follows :

```
asyncProcess()
    .then(log.bind(null, "1"))
    .then(log.bind(null, "2"))
    .then(log.bind(null, "3"))
    .then(log.bind(null, "4"))
    .then(log.bind(null, "5"))
    .then(log.bind(null, "6"))
    .then(log.bind(null, "7"));

// Note that .then() takes functions as arguments so `.bind(...)` is necessary to establish functions with bound-in arguments, without actually executing `log("1"); log("2"); log("3");` etc at the time the .then() chain is established.
```

As long as `asyncProcess()` returns a Promise that :

- is already resolved
- becomes resolved at some time in the future,

the functions specified in the `.then()` chain will execute and 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 will appear in your log.

In its simplest form, `asyncProcess` might look like this :

```
function asyncProcess() {
    return $.when(); //return a resolved promise
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/04npLt9e/)**

To be slightly more adventurous, and to give the promise chain some purpose, you could explore its ability to convey data.

First, adapt `asyncProcess()` to return a promise resolved with a number passed as a parameter to the function :

```
function asyncProcess(n) {
    return $.when(n);//return a promise resolved with the valie 1
}
```

Then, adapt `log()` to accept a number `n`, log it, and return `n+1`:

```
function log(n) {
    $('#log').append('<p>' + n + '</p>');
    return n + 1;
}
```

And adapt the promise chain as follows :

```
asyncProcess(1)
    .then(log)
    .then(log)
    .then(log)
    .then(log)
    .then(log)
    .then(log)
    .then(log);
```

Here, the need for `.bind()` disappears as the raw `log` is used without any bound-in parameters. The parameter in each call of `log` is provided by the return value of the previous call.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/04npLt9e/2/)**

Comment: I try this way but for image loading, this logic appear to be wrong, there is a way to load image in a queue (by the way in specific order) and in total loading time to have done/fail methods ?
I saw that code : http://jsfiddle.net/coffeeandcode/yg9P6/ which implement queue but the problem in this case, use of 'setTimeout' and not possible to add done/fail for end queue.